# Excel vba enter dynamic printranges

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic, range

I'm trying to put together a code where I can choose which ranges to print using a inputbox/userform. My workbook contains a general part (that must be printed always) with range `("B2;K" & lrow)`. Proyectnames, starting dates, autor, etc. can be found here.

Starting from column L till column JL are the weeknumbers of the year including the days (mon-fri). I have given every week a rangename, e.g. weeknumber 1 is "week1" with range `("L2;M" & lrow)`, weeknumber 2 is "week2" with range `("N2;R" & lrow)` etc.

What I would like the code to do, is to print the general part and the weeknumbers you have entered in a popup box (e.g. inputbox/userform).

*Week (starts):*
1

*Week (ends):*
7

The code will now print the general part + week 1 to week 7 onto the same sheet. Is this possible?

The code I have now works, but only for for 1 range:

```
Dim PrintRange As String
Dim lrow As Long

lrow = Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row + 1
    ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = Range("B2:K" & lrow).Address(1, 1)

    Do
      PrintRange = InputBox("Enter weeknumbers ...", "Determine range")
      If PrintRange = "" Then Exit Sub
    Loop Until Val(PrintRange)

PrintRange = "week" & Trim(PrintRange)

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    On Error Resume Next
    .Goto Range(PrintRange)

    If Err Then
        MsgBox "Range " & Chr(34) & PrintRange & _
               Chr(34) & " doesn't exit", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If

    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With
Selection.PrintOut Copies:=1, Preview:=True
```

I hope I clarified my problem. Thank you for your time

Comment: If your weeks are in different columns, could you just hide the columns that do not need printed?

Comment: Every week overlapses 5 very small columns (monday to friday). It is almost impossible to select a specific column, only if you zoom in to 150% you can select the correct ones. That is why I rather prefer to use a macro if possible. Can you help with that?

Comment: That's what I meant. Hide the columns in your macro so they don't show up when you print. You can then unhide them after you're done printing.

Comment: This brings me to the same question but the other way around, how can I choose the columns that I want to hide? Let's say I want to hide week 1 to week 6 using a macro. If this can be done using a inputbox/userform, I asume printing instead of hiding will also be possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I'm understanding your question has two parts:

1. You want to be able to have `("B2;K" & lrow)` print every time, regardless of which weeks are selected.
2. You want the user to be able to select multiple weeks at a time.

**Part 1**

In order to have a certain range print every time, I suggest using the Print Titles feature in Excel. To use this feature, go to Page Layout->Print Titles. Under the "Sheet" tab, type `$B:$K` in for the "Columns to repeat at left". This will ensure that the information in columns B through K prints every time, regardless of the selection.

Also, if you want everything to print on one page no matter what, I would suggest changing your "Orientation" to "Landscape" and changing the "Width" in your "Scale to Fit" to "1 page". Both of these are also under the Page Layout tab.

**Part 2**

I'm not sure what your loop is doing around your input box, but if you use `Application.InputBox` and change the `Type`, you can make the box only allow numeric inputs. You can then have two input boxes: one for the starting week and one for the ending week. Replace your code with this:

```
Sub PrintWeeks()

Dim PrintRangeStart As Long
Dim PrintRange1     As Range
Dim PrintRangeEnd   As Long
Dim PrintRange2     As Range
Dim ErrorCheck      As Long

PrintRangeStart = Application.InputBox("Enter the starting week number...", "Determine range start", Type:=1)
PrintRangeEnd = Application.InputBox("Enter the ending week number...", "Determine range end", Type:=1)

On Error GoTo Error_Handling
ErrorCheck = 1
Set PrintRange1 = Range("week" & PrintRangeStart)
ErrorCheck = 2
Set PrintRange2 = Range("week" & PrintRangeEnd)
On Error GoTo 0

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = Range(PrintRange1.Address(1, 1), PrintRange2.Address(PrintRange2.Rows.Count, PrintRange2.Columns.Count)).Address
ActiveSheet.PrintPreview

Error_Handling:
    If ErrorCheck = 1 And Err.Number <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "Range ""week" & PrintRangeStart & """ doesn't exist.", vbExclamation
    ElseIf ErrorCheck = 2 And Err.Number <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "Range ""week" & PrintRangeEnd & """ doesn't exist.", vbExclamation
    ElseIf Err.Number <> 0 Then
        MsgBox Err & ": " & Error(Err)
    End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Unfortunately, I was not able to get the print preview function working properly, so this will just print directly without a preview.

**EDIT**

If you want to add the Print Titles through code, just add `Sheets("Sheet1").PageSetup.PrintTitleColumns = "$B:$K"` anywhere before the `PrintOut` line, and change "Sheet1" to reference your sheet.

**EDIT 2**

I've edited the printing lines to change the print area each time instead of relying on the selection. This way you can use the print preview as well. Hopefully that will help alleviate any of your other issues.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I was looking for. Only the part that always has to be printed does not seem to work, I did what you said but it does not come out with the weeks I choose to print. How can I incorperate this general part in the macro? I have tried it, but what I only seem to accomplish is to print the general part to the "ending week number". E.g if I want week 5 to 10, it will print the general part + week 1 to 10. So it includes week 1 to 4. I have named the range as "proyectinfo". Any sugestions?

Comment: Have you tested it manually? With the Print Titles on, select a range to print, pull up the print dialog, select "Selection" under "Print What", and hit Preview. I'm not sure why it would be printing all of the weeks when you only want a few, unless one of the named ranges is not referencing the correct range.

Comment: @M.Bergh I've added a line to my answer for adding the Print Titles through code if you want.

Comment: Thank you! Now it works exactly as I had in mind, really appreciate your help and time. Cheers

Comment: Great! I just got done adding another edit that changes the print area each time instead of relying on the selection. I think this is a cleaner approach as I try to avoid selecting data in my macros. If you would like me to change this back to the way it was, please let me know.

Comment: This one also works for me, no need to change it back. I spent a lot of time trying to figure this one out, but without any luck, so thanks again for your time!

Comment: I know it has been a while but I have another question as an addition to your answer. Every week there are more and more rows added and by now it is hard to read, everything is getting printed on a paper size A3. So my question is if pagebreaks can be added? A while back someone helped me with it for another document I was making:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28959736/add-page-break-every-x-rows-after-specific-value-excel-vba   I have tried to add his answer to your code but without any luck. Every help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm thinking you just need to change your "Width" in "Scale to Fit" back to "Automatic" and adjust your "Scale" to your liking. Just be aware of how it will print if you have more than one page vertically and horizontally. You may want to change the "Page order" to "Over, then down" in the "Page Setup" box. The page breaks will be put in automatically once the "Width" is changed back from "1 page" to "Automatic".